# i want to create a app like instagram but i want java code for learning image sharing apps like instagram

Tags: android

I want to make a image sharing and uploading app just like instagram on android.But im not getting a java coding for that, I want a java tutorial for a image sharing app, where will I get it

Comment: You can't just ask us to do your googling for you, you know. Creating an app like that isn't as easy as it sounds.

I'd look up seperate tutorials, one for uploading an image to a server, and one for getting one from the server.

Comment: you can probably use anypic https://www.anypic.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here is some reference https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/02/android-share-intent-example.html Hope it helps